# Categorical axis in Holoviews Curve leads to error

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews

I have this data

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQxY-rTQNBbMWtRI2p8m_gj0TvmkHt3_CqNkhRILq6s5xL3mGX-IXtZt9pej-ae3ZNN1EnAP_iC0unx/pub?output=csv', index=False)

df.head()
Id  Year    Period  Cumulative  YearPeriod  YearPeriodStr
0   16432976    1   1   6.0 11  Period 11
1   16432976    1   2   7.0 12  Period 12
2   16432976    1   0   0.0 10  Period 10
3   16879454    1   1   6.0 11  Period 11
4   16879454    1   2   6.0 12  Period 12
```

What I want to achieve is a combination of two ordinal variables on the x-axis. The first level should be Year, the second Period. The following code is what I thought would lead to the graph I want:

```
%opts Curve [width=600 height=400 show_grid=True default_tools=['save','hover',]  show_legend=False] (color='indianred', alpha=0.3, line_width=0.2, )

ds = hv.Dataset(df).sort(['Year','Period'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, ['Year','Period'],'Cumulative', 'Id').overlay()
```

But this puts Period on the y-axis. The following code gets me closer to what I want:

```
%opts Curve [width=600 height=400 show_grid=True default_tools=['save','hover',]  show_legend=False] (color='indianred', alpha=0.3, line_width=0.2, )

# Numerical column
df['YearPeriod'] = (df.Year * 10) + (df.Period)
ds = hv.Dataset(df).sort(['Year','Period'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, 'YearPeriod','Cumulative', 'Id').overlay()
```

But the x-axis now is a continuous variable, while what I want is the second level, Period, to be ordinal. 
The following code leads more or less to what I want, but fails when the amount of rows exceeds 120.

```
%opts Curve [width=600 height=400 show_grid=True default_tools=['save','hover',]  show_legend=False] (color='indianred', alpha=0.3, line_width=0.2, )

# String
df['YearPeriodStr'] = 'Period'+ df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Period'].astype(str)

ds = hv.Dataset(df.head(120)).sort(['Year','Period'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, 'YearPeriodStr','Cumulative', 'Id').overlay()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There appears to be an issue with the batched optimization when using a categorical axis, which combines individual line glyphs into a single multi_line glyph. You can disable the optimization with: ``%opts NdOverlay [batched=False]``. I've opened an issue to address this: https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/2364

Separately ``ds.to(hv.Curve, ['Year','Period'],'Cumulative', 'Id')`` does not yet work, but should once https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/1668 has been addressed.

Comment: Once again, thanks, this is very helpfull!

Comment: Sorting of the x-axis (categorical YearPeriodStr) doesn't seem to work in this scenario. Is this related to one of the mentioned issues?